# how to increase font size of a link

Tags: html, css

I am brand new to coding and just need to understand how to make the font size of my link larger.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
color: #43c6de;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
color: #43c6de;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="(linkaddress)">Have an iPhone? Download the Beta App Here!
</a>
```

Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: `a {font-size:150%}`

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=change%20font%20size%20css

Comment: a { font-size: 2em; } or a.classname { font-size: 2em;  }

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

To change the size of a link, simply use the following CSS code:

```
a {
    font-size: 50px; /* example size, can be any size, in px, em, rem, % */
}
```

```css
a {
   font-size: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Test Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options: Increase the size of your font by percent:

```
a { font-size:150%; }
```

or by a fixed size:

```css
a { font-size:30px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be the `font-size` CSS property you would need to work with:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

There are numerous ways to specify the font size: absolute and relative.  These are explained in the above link.